# How to use Bluetooth to connect to a laptop and adjust the volume with Flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I'm developing an application that needs to be able to get volume data from my laptop and be able to adjust it.

I first wanted to try capturing the volume information on the laptop, but I didn't know how...
and be able to adjust your laptop's volume using Android.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

To control your laptop's volume using a Flutter application via Bluetooth, you would need to create a connection between your Flutter app and your laptop. There is a project on GitHub called Flutter Bluetooth PC Control which outlines a way to control a PC using a Flutter app via Bluetooth, and this could be adapted for volume control​​​​.

https://github.com/ganeshsp1/Flutter_Bluetooth_PC_Control

Here's a general approach on how this could work:

You would first need to establish a Bluetooth connection between your Flutter app and your laptop by pairing the devices and creating a communication channel.

On the laptop side, you would need a service running that can listen for Bluetooth communication and adjust the system volume accordingly. This could be a Java application that uses system calls to control the volume​​.

In your Flutter app, you would use a Bluetooth plugin, like flutter_blue or a similar package, to handle the Bluetooth communication. Your app would send messages to the laptop service to adjust the volume up or down.

The Flutter app would need a user interface that allows the user to control the volume. This could be a simple slider or buttons to increase and decrease the volume.

Comment: OMG, thank you for your answer! I am a newbie in flutter. There are not so many resources in my country, but I should first use English to find relevant information. I'm sorry⋯